# Google cloud storage bucket [GCS bucket total bytes]- metrics missing for a specific bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, monitoring, google-cloud-storage

**Update: The metrics appeared after more than 24 hours**

I have a lot of buckets in my GCP project (some regional and some multi-region) and I'm able to get the metric: `'storage.googleapis.com/storage/total_bytes'` for all of them except one.

I've not created the rest, just this problematic one - but I cant find anything in the configuration that may be responsible for metrics collection for that bucket. What may be the cause of this?

This is the full query I am using:

```
fetch gcs_bucket
| metric 'storage.googleapis.com/storage/total_bytes'
| filter (resource.bucket_name == '')
| group_by 1m, [value_total_bytes_mean: mean(value.total_bytes)]
| every 1m
| group_by [resource.bucket_name],
    [value_total_bytes_mean_aggregate: aggregate(value_total_bytes_mean)]
```

Comment: When did you create the bucket? There is a delay before data is available.

Comment: IIRC that metric is measured once per day and there is a delay after measurement before the value becomes available for you to query. Let us know tomorrow if that is the case.

Comment: @JohnHanley so far it is not visible